# Symfony - Set an Entity to a ManyToOne

Tags: php, symfony, json-api

Ok guys i ask you a simple question how can i set an entity who is not in parameter

I am trying this method :

```
    $em_category = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category'))));
    $userInterest->setUser($user);

    $userInterest->setCategory($em_category);
```

But when i do that i have this error :

> Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Category" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest#$category", got "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" instead.

So how can i set to userinterest the category that i want ...? 
Thx for all that will try to answer :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variably `$em_category` is your entity manager, the class that performs the data storage and retrieval from the database. You need to use it to get the category, then pass that value on to `setCategory`. Like so.

```
$cat = $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category'))));
$userInterest->setCategory($cat);
```